# UIWebView throwing exception for [WebActionDisablingCALayerDelegate setBeingRemoved:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios8

When running against iOS 8, I began to see the following exception coming from the deep bowels of `UIWebView`:

> [WebActionDisablingCALayerDelegate setBeingRemoved:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x167ee900
>
> *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:willRemoveScrollingLayer:withContentsLayer:forNode: delegate:  -[WebActionDisablingCALayerDelegate setBeingRemoved:

This is happening when I change some constraints on my `UIWebView` and then call:

```
 self.webViewWidthConstraints.constant = newWidth;
 [self.webView setNeedsLayout];
 [self.webView layoutIfNeeded];
```

(This is so that the webview's content is re-rendered to fit its width correctly).

Luckily the exception is discarded, so the app isn't crashing. Why is this happening, and is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: I got the same exception in cordova application with iframe.

Comment: Yeah with cordova (((

Comment: Same here. Not using cordova.
Having a simple webview displayed as a modal view and rotating the device raises this exception (iOS8 only, worked in iOS7)

Comment: Ok, so i fixed issues for me - problem was in JS with calculating width for one of the text field.

Comment: I'm currently using this exclusion rule for a breakpoint on objc_exception_throw to keep these exceptions from pausing the debugger: !(BOOL)[[$r0 reason] hasPrefix:@"-[WebActionDisablingCALayerDelegate setBeingRemoved:]"]

Answer (score 12):

I found that by adding "-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);" to the scrollable content (I have a div inside my scrollable container), it fixed the issue for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: I put this on my `body` tag and it fixed everything

Comment: Since you can't ask the world wide web to add a `-webkit-transform`, the solution lies in migrating to `WKWebView`, since `UIWebView` is, in essence, deprecated.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this is your case, but I also started seeing this problem on iOS 8 and we tracked it down to the usage of the following CSS property on an iframe:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

After we removed it, we no longer had those error messages.

Note: in my case, it didn't happen in response to changing any constraints, but rather it happened while we were navigating through the HTML.

Comment: In my instance, this was happening when there were two or more `<div>` elements present in a single webview with the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` property.

Answer (score 7):

As none of the answers given could help me I had to resolve this issue with help of Objective-C runtime.

First I've provided a simple function:

```
id setBeingRemoved(id self, SEL selector, ...)
{
   return nil;
}
```

Then these two lines:

```
    Class class = NSClassFromString(@"WebActionDisablingCALayerDelegate");
    class_addMethod(class, @selector(setBeingRemoved:), setBeingRemoved, NULL);
```

And it works.

Comment: Please, could you provide more details on this implementation? I tried to implement it, and had a bunch of issues. Thanks

Comment: hi! what details do you need exactly?

Comment: I'm in the need of override more methods, at least in iOS 8.4.1. Please see [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/hjnx2i0E). At least, seems that it doesn't crash now. I've nearly 'disabled' all the methods in that delegate

Comment: sorry, I don't get you. You're doing everything just right. what's your problem?

Comment: Sometimes it calls new functions, It's somewhat working now. Feel free to update your answer with my code. Thanks Andrey :)

Comment: After using this for 2.5 years, our latest app-update got rejected because of this. Fortunately, this is no longer needed in recent iOS-SDKs.

Answer (score 4):

**Use [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) instead of UIWebView**. (it was first included in iOS 8). I've tried it, and seems that it hasn't got this bug. Also, it may improve the performance compared with it predecessor. Seems likely that Apple will make the de-facto standard in the near future, if not now. It has interfaces and delegates somewhat similar to UIWebView. Definitively worth a try.

If you are targeting pre-iOS 8, you can implement fallback procedures to load either UIWebView or WKWebView, [here you are](https://github.com/gowithfloat/FLWebView) an out-of-the-box implementation

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was a <table> inside of iframe content. The table width was greater than the iframe width defined via CSS. The iframe scrolling was off, and the table has stretched the iframe to the minimum calculated width of the table. Other side effect: content of the iframe was not completely visible (cut off on the right side).

```
|--- Available viewport width -------------|
|--- defined and estimated iframe width ---|
|--- table width in the iframe content > than defined iframe width ---|
|--- iframe stretched to the calculated table width ------------------|
```

Removing the table form iframe content has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @André Morujão answered, removing `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` from the scrolling element stops the exception. But I found that the exception was only happening when I added `display:none` css to the scrolling element.

Edit: I was able to continue using `display:none` to hide my scrolling element by putting `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;` inside of its own class `.scroll` and using jquery to add and remove that class from my scrolling element before and after hiding it:

```
<style>
    .scroll
    {
         -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    }
</style>
<script>
function hide()
{
    $('#scrolling_element).removeClass('scroll');
    $('#scrolling_element).css('display', 'none');
}
function show()
{
    $('#scrolling_element).css('display', 'block');
    $('#scrolling_element).addClass('scroll');
}
</script>
```