# WebKit throwing exception on iOS 8 for call to setBeingRemoved:

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webkit, ios8

I have an app which relies on UIWebViews for some of its screens, but starting on iOS 8 I started seeing the following exception being thrown occasionally:

***WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:willRemoveScrollingLayer:withContentsLayer:forNode: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[WebActionDisablingCALayerDelegate setBeingRemoved:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance (...)***

This will normally happen in response to tapping a button or link on the webview (without anything else going on on the Objective-C side), and after that most of the functionality in the webview will be broken (links not clickable, etc).

I have seen at least one other question referring to this error message, but no conclusive answers yet.

Has anyone ran into this issue and figured out what was wrong / what causes it?
It appears to depend entirely on the HTML content, meaning that the fact that this exception is thrown is an iOS 8 bug.

Comment: The error message _is_ complete (unless you're referring to the (...), which was the variable's address). Regarding code: the reason I didn't include it was because this depends on the HTML, and nothing on the HTML should cause this kind of exception on the Objective-C side. I have seen other complaints of this exception, which certainly have a different HTML source, and the main point here is that this error does not happen on iOS 7, only iOS 8.

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't help either, it just breaks on main() with nothing else on the stack trace.

Comment: I just read this, haven't tried it yet, but here it is: http://patrickmuff.ch/blog/2014/10/01/how-we-fixed-the-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-bug-on-ios/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this error was caused by the use of the following CSS property on an iframe in my HTML:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Removed it (we're now looking for a suitable alternative) and the UIWebView no longer crashes.

Comment: Not sure if you are still looking but I just posted a fix where I could keep those styles

Comment: Well, I am having this crash when loading Google search result. I can't change Google CSS, so I wonder if there is any way to protect from the crash.

Comment: @Sundraw did you find a solution for this? I'm getting this error when loading a Google search result

Answer (score 3):

**You can use [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) instead of UIWebView**. (it was first included in iOS 8). I've tried it, and seems that it hasn't got this bug.

If you are targeting pre-iOS 8, you can implement fallback procedures to load either UIWebView or WKWebView, [here you are](https://github.com/gowithfloat/FLWebView) an out-of-the-box implementation

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, but unfortunately I'm still stuck with using UIWebView for the time being (some of the features I'm using are still not available on WKWebView).

Answer (score 1):

I put `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px)` on my `body` element. Seems to fix the issue and I could keep the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` styles.

Also seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26806642/580487

Comment: Wish I knew about this earlier... if only iOS8 UIWebView would just work like Safari!

Comment: I had two causes of this error.  This was ONE of them.  The other was multiple `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` styles in the same HTML.  This solution let me keep ONE of them

Answer (score 0):

I changed padding: 0 16px 0 26%; to margin-left: 25%; and it works for me